# Ctypes, C extension, and outside library: Cast Long to Void Pointer

Tags: python, casting, ctypes, void-pointers

I built a thin wrapper around a C library using `ctypes` that I'm trying to improve now. The library has an `add_datum(*graph,int)` function that I've wrapped (including the `Structure` for `graph`), and it runs successfully.

The problem is I need to call this function more than 2 million times, and performance is suffering terribly. I implemented a short C function `add_data(*graph, int[])` that does the same as repeated calls to `add_datum(*graph, int)`. By saving on some redundant C-level validation of `*graph` and the 2M+ python function calls, I've greatly improved execution time.

My concern is about the portability of code, since I'm having to cast a Python integer, as returned by `ctypes.addressof`, to a `*void`.

Here are the relevant bits of code (error checking, decrefing stripped out):

```
int extract_graph(PyObject* pygraph, graph** mygraph) {
  PyObject* ctypes_ptr, graph_obj, addr_obj;
  ctypes_ptr = PyObject_GetAttrString(pygraph, "graph_ptr");
  graph_obj = PyObject_GetAttrString(ctypes_ptr, "contents");
  addr_obj = PyObject_CallFunctionObjArgs(addressof, graph_obj);
  *mygraph = (graph*) PyLong_AsVoidPtr(addr_obj); /* <-------------------------- */
```

And the python class def:

```
class PyGraph(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.graph_ptr = ctypes.pointer(c_Graph())
```

Is this robust and cross-platform? From what I've been able to find on Google/SO it appears `ctypes` doesn't have a friendlier C API.

I'm only concerned because of [PEP 353](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0353/), which, frankly, went a little over my head.

Comment: Depending on the platform, `PyLong_AsVoidPtr` either uses `PyLong_AsLong` or `PyLong_AsLongLong`. On 64-bit Windows a `long` is only 32-bit, so Python instead uses a `long long`. Casting the `void *` isn't an issue, but I have to ask what's up with using `pointer` just to dereference it and call `addressof` on the graph?

Comment: Instead of an extension module I'd put `add_data` in another lib and call it with ctypes. You can link it against the original lib if you decide to call `add_datum`.

Comment: To complete eryksun's comment, I'd recommend to try out http://cffi.readthedocs.org.  It's an alternative to ctypes which supports out of the box things like writing a small custom function in C, that invokes the original functions.

Comment: Thank you both for the advice. There are a couple of other things I need to do for which using iterators makes a lot of sense from a memory point of view, so another ctypes lib won't work (I think). I'll look into CFFI to see if I can get that running.